# Why does CSS not work within the div?

Tags: css, html

I have the following :

```css
.defaultGrid{
    width:     100%;
}
.defaultGrid table{
    width:      100%;
}
.defaultGrid .pageBCon{
    float:                      right;
}

.defaultGrid .gridTest tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #e9d5b6;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="defaultGrid, gridTest">
        <div class="pageBCon">Pages</div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>test1</td>
                    <td>test1</td>
                    <td>test1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>test1</td>
                    <td>test1</td>
                    <td>test1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>test1</td>
                    <td>test1</td>
                    <td>test1</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

AS you can see, the HTML elements under the div is not getting correct css? Why?

Comment: `class="defaultGrid, gridTest"` should be `class="defaultGrid gridTest"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code.

**HTML:** When you apply multiple classes to an element, you need to separate them using a white-space, not a comma:

```
<div class="defaultGrid gridTest">
```

**CSS**: In your `nth-child` rule, you have an extra white-space in the rule definition. It should be:

```
.defaultGrid.gridTest tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #e9d5b6;
}
```

`.defaultGrid .gridTest` (with white-space) means `grid.test` that is a child of `.defaultGrid`.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdt67yx5/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.defaultGrid{
    width:     100%;
}
.defaultGrid table{
    width:      100%;
}
.defaultGrid .pageBCon{
    float:                      right;
}

.defaultGrid .gridTest tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #e9d5b6;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="defaultGrid gridTest">
        <div class="pageBCon">Pages</div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>test1</td>
                    <td>test1</td>
                    <td>test1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>test1</td>
                    <td>test1</td>
                    <td>test1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>test1</td>
                    <td>test1</td>
                    <td>test1</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

You just need to remove comma from the class. Instead of `<div class="defaultGrid, gridTest">` do `<div class="defaultGrid gridTest">`

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the comma. Do not use commas to separate selector classes. It's defaultGrid.gridTest in the css selector.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML this not valid

```
<div class="defaultGrid, gridTest">
```

but to give a DIV more than one class you should do that:

```
<div class="defaultGrid gridTest">
```

Comment: `<div class="defaultGrid, gridTest">` *is* valid HTML. It can even be made use use of in CSS with care. http://jsfiddle.net/Lmucw03f/1/